# PHP Mcrypt and Base64 encode decode return strange characters

Tags: php, decode, encode, mcrypt

I have used the following to encode and decode a simple string "abcdefg123"

```
function encryptIt( $q ) {
    $cryptKey  = 'fkEir8eu0ajiOo93q32txY';
    $qEncoded      = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), $q, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ) );
    return( $qEncoded );
}

function decryptIt( $q ) {
    $cryptKey  = 'fkEir8eu0ajiOo93q32txY';
    $qDecoded      = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), base64_decode( $q ), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ), "\0");
    return( $qDecoded );
}
```

I get encoded A/ziTyvagw4vgKbIOOdvP1zy15p0mkY6hIYSJcE2Kq4=
but decoded returns 8��M�j�3l0�q��M�#�蟂T��@�mҾQ

I have read the other solutions here at stackoverflow like utf8_decode() and rawurlencode(), but still can't seems to get it to work. I am using php 7.

Comment: Actually it seems to work in PHP 7.1 sandbox: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9cf0288ee95dd0d21d0490f9079b9e1e470ee9ed but the `mcrypt` extension is deprecated in that version. How are you testing it?

Comment: why do you need this complex encrypting/ decrypting functions?

Comment: I am actually using it to encode and decode a more complex string "link=aaa&pass=defg" but i tried it with even a simple string it still does not work.

i am using the following to do the testing

$linker='abcdefg123';
echo $linker;
echo '<br>';
 echo encryptIt($linker);
echo '<br>';
echo decryptIt($linker);

Comment: It is best not to use PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: In mcrypt `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` means a block size of 256-bits, not the key size. Generally what is desired is AES (Advanced Encryption **Standard**) and for that the block size must be 128-bits so use `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`. But **don't use mcrtypt**, it is a POS.

Comment: WRT the returned string: Encryption is byte based, not string/character based. Most byte values do not have a display representation and the `�` indicted a non-displayable character. To obtain a displayable character representational of encrypted data the usual method is to Base64 encode the encrypted data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
define('ENCRYPTION_KEY', md5("fkEir8eu0ajiOo93q32txY"));
// Encrypt Function
function mc_encrypt($encrypt, $key){
    $encrypt = serialize($encrypt);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $key = pack('H*', $key);
    $mac = hash_hmac('sha256', $encrypt, substr(bin2hex($key), -32));
    $passcrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $encrypt.$mac, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $encoded = base64_encode($passcrypt).'|'.base64_encode($iv);
    return $encoded;
}
// Decrypt Function
function mc_decrypt($decrypt, $key){
    $decrypt = explode('|', $decrypt.'|');
    $decoded = base64_decode($decrypt[0]);
    $iv = base64_decode($decrypt[1]);
    if(strlen($iv)!==mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)){ return false; }
    $key = pack('H*', $key);
    $decrypted = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
    $mac = substr($decrypted, -64);
    $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -64);
    $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $decrypted, substr(bin2hex($key), -32));
    if($calcmac!==$mac){ return false; }
    $decrypted = unserialize($decrypted);
    return $decrypted;
}
$data = 'abcdefg123';
$encrypted_data = mc_encrypt($data, ENCRYPTION_KEY);
echo 'Data to be Encrypted: ' . $data . '<br/>';
echo 'Encrypted Data: ' . $encrypted_data . '<br/>';
echo 'Decrypted Data: ' . mc_decrypt($encrypted_data, ENCRYPTION_KEY) . '</br>';
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! This worked magically! But I still do not quite understand your code and what went wrong with the my original code.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if it pointed out that `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` is non-standard where AES is (by definition) and `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 is AES`. Also an explanation oif the Base64 encoding. The comment by the OP shows that while this code works there is no real answer to the question, that is **why** it solves the issue. Please consider improving the answer.